# How to iterate array of arrays using knockout data-bind foreach?

Tags: knockout.js

I have an array of arrays that contain objects, and im looking for a way to loop over the inner arrays of the array, something like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: questions">
    <div data-bind="foreach: subArray of questions">
        <span data-bind="text: Title"></span>
        <span data-bind="text: Answer"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i access the inner arrays of the questions observableArray so i can loop over the elements?

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/373672/)

thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/373803/) . To use inner loop knockout has provided various properties like `$data`, to use outer loop `$parent`.

```
<div class="answers" data-bind="foreach: questions">
    <div data-bind="foreach: $data ">
      <p data-bind="text: Title"></p>
      <p data-bind="text: Answer"></p>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the docs, you just have to access inner arrays with `$data`: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html

```
<div class="answers" data-bind="foreach: questions">
  <div data-bind="foreach: $data ">
    <p data-bind="text: Title"></p>
    <p data-bind="text: Answer"></p>  
  </div>
</div>
```